# Getting error "Resources exceeded during query execution" in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

I have a table in Bigquery and I am applying following transformation

```
    SELECT *, 
      CASE WHEN type = 'Monthly' THEN DATE_TRUNC(dt, MONTH) ELSE FIRST_VALUE(DATE_TRUNC(program_end_date, MONTH)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC) END AS activity_month
      from table
```

If my type is monthly then I pick it from dt column or i will get latest value. Here I am getting following error

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 121% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 99% other/unattributed: 1%
```

I know why it is failing, since there is ORDER BY in my partition its trying to put in single node and node's memory was not enough to get result. But if my transformation needs order by, how do i avoid it? Here i can not divide table as it might cause inconsistencies. My table has 2.4 billion rows and it is trying to process 576GB. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hope this is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494385/bigquery-resources-exceeded-when-computing-running-sum/72496356#72496356

Comment: `id` sounds like the primary key of the table, if so what does `PARTITION BY ID` achieve? the system has to create 2.4 billion groups and order each by date (admittedly there will be one row in each).

Comment: Thanks tinzmu for your comment. No id is not primary key. if its monthly, in a particular month it will be 30 rows and one time can be extended to random number of days. so it wont create 2.4 billion groups

Comment: You could try to split the query in different stage tables, first, have one with just the partition transformation then you can get the first value from there then you can use the case.